# is there any difference in php-mongo codes for insertion for 32 bit and 64 bit mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

i used these codes to insert a new document with sub-document array into mongodb, its still working in 32bit mongo

```
$product = array(
                    'field1' => "value",
                    'field2' => "value",
                    'field3' => "value",

                    'field4'=> 
                    [array
                        (
                            'subfield1'=>"value",
                            'subfield2' => "value",
                            'subfield3' =>"unknown",
                            'subfield4'  =>"unknown",
                            'subfield5'    =>"unknown",
                            'subfield6'=>"n"
                        )
                    ],



                    );
                    $collection->insert( $product );
```

this works perfectly

but when i use the same code in 64bit mongo no insertion occurs,

i replaced the '[' with '(' then insertion occured but instead of getting a subdocument array i am getting just a subdocument object

that is instead of this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f2f2ee4c3f9f33c6b72464"),
"field1" : "value",
"field2" : "value",
"field3" : [
    {
        "subfield1" : "Miles to go before i sleep",
        "subfield2" : "song",
        "subfield3" : "long before"
    }
           ]
}
```

i am getting this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f2f2ee4c3f9f33c6b72464"),
"field1" : "value",
"field2" : "value",
"field3" : 
    {
        "subfield1" : "Miles to go before i sleep",
        "subfield2" : "song",
        "subfield3" : "long before"
    }

}
```

but i can insert it via mongo shell, only with mongo shell not via php-mongo, also i cannot add subdocuments to the same that is add another subfield array to field 3 via php-mongo
please help i am desperate

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, gave me a lot of stress, but the solution was so sinple,

instead of using `[` use '(array(' this is the only change, '64bit' or its version or something else dont support array as giving `[` in php-mongo query. this the working code

```
 $product = array(
                'field1' => "value",
                'field2' => "value",
                'field3' => "value",

                'field4'=> 
                (
               array( 
                  array(
                        'subfield1'=>"value",
                        'subfield2' => "value",
                        'subfield3' =>"unknown",
                        'subfield4'  =>"unknown",
                        'subfield5'    =>"unknown",
                        'subfield6'=>"n"
                    )
                )
             ),



                );
                $collection->insert( $product );
```